# Tree View not showing update

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView in my Windows Form user interface. 
I want to fill it up from a database, but it does not refresh ever, even though if I WriteLine() every node, it is in memory as I expect.

In order to make it more easy to understand, I wrote a little example program that only has one button that creates a TreeView and a TreeView called treeView1 to display its content.

If anyone can tell me where I have misunderstood the use of the TreeView, it would be a tremendous help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create a tree
        TreeView t = new TreeView();
        TreeNode[] child = new TreeNode [1];
            child[0]=new TreeNode("myCat");
            child[0].Name = "IndependantOne";
            TreeNode categoryNode = new TreeNode("catIdTag", child);
            categoryNode.Name = "Citizen Cat 5239002147";
            t.Nodes.Add(categoryNode);
                // some stuff under the first node
                TreeNode[] mouseNode = new TreeNode[1];
                mouseNode[0] = new TreeNode("myMouse");
                mouseNode[0].Name = "SqueakyOne";
                TreeNode[] childItem = new TreeNode[1];
                childItem[0] = new TreeNode("mouseIdTag", mouseNode);
                childItem[0].Name = "Citizen Mouse 54655654649";
                TreeNode eltNode = new TreeNode("Cheese", childItem);
                eltNode.Name = "Emmental";
                t.Nodes["Citizen Cat 5239002147"].Nodes.Add(eltNode);

        // fill in the winform treeview
                if (t != null)
                {
                    //treeView1.Visible = false;
                    treeView1.BeginUpdate();
                    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                    treeView1.TopNode = t.TopNode;
                    foreach (TreeNode n in t.Nodes)
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes.Add(n);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Category Node contains: " + treeView1.Nodes[n.Name].Name + " at " + treeView1.Nodes[n.Name].Level);
                        foreach (TreeNode no in treeView1.Nodes[n.Name].Nodes)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Category Node Nodes contains: " + no.Name);
                        }
                    }
                    /*
                    This part I tried and it doesn't work either, still add it in the question if anyone knows if it's wiser?
                    this.treeView1 = t;
                    this.treeView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(233, 12);
                    this.treeView1.Name = "treeView1";
                    this.treeView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(351, 277);
                    this.treeView1.TabIndex = 11;
                    this.treeView1.AfterSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.treeView1_AfterSelect);
                    */
                    treeView1.EndUpdate();
                    this.treeView1.Update();
                    this.treeView1.Refresh();

                    treeView1.Show();
                    //this.Refresh();
                }


    }
```

I also tried setting the treeView1 with

```
 treeView1 = t;
```

It was not a success...

Comment: drag and drop tree view to your form and set id as treeView1  and comment `TreeView t = new TreeView();` line of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add(n);
```

with

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)n.Clone());
```

You cannot host the same node in more than one `TreeView` control.

Alternatively, you can remove nodes from source `TreeView` before adding them to other `TreeView`:

```
while(t.Nodes.Count != 0)
{
    var node = t.Nodes[0];
    t.Nodes.RemoveAt(0);
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

And I hope that there is a real reason why you create and fill tree view in your method instead of directly filling an already existing one. If it is not an intended behavior, remove the `if` block completely and change `TreeView t = new TreeView();` to `var t = treeView1`.

Comment: The reason I create a new Treeview is, while I'm uploading the information from the database, I want the previous Treeview to be displayed in the UI. So I reasonned I'd make a new one and hotswitch them when the networking operation, inherently slower than a UI refresh, would have completed :D

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is expected because with this code you`re confusing node-to-treeview relationship nature of the native .NET treeview control. Instead when moving nodes between treeviews (t -> treeView1) you need to clone them as suggested. Without that moved node still linked with the old treeview (see node.Treeview property) and because original tree (t) is not visible/added to any parent (form), *I guess* node will be invisible as well.

Also, the way you`re working with data loading (through creating new treeview) is pretty bad pattern. Instead you need to download your data (async I guess) into a temp buffer and recreate the treeView1 at once when data will be available with BeginUpdate/EndUpdate calls.

PS. Replacing treeView1 *variable* with 't' won't work as well because you don't replace the treeview control *instance* in the parent form/panel Controls property with this code.